# Check the log file on Android

Tags: android

I created an app for Android mobile. I installed apk file on the device through Eclipse. While installing or running the app, I am able to see the log files in logcat when the device is connected to the computer using usb cable.

I would like to see the log files in the same way when the device is not connected though USB cable on the device. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: For Android 4.1+ you can't, to my knowledge, do to security reasons. But for pre-4.1 you can install [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd) from the market.

Comment: Hey @Ashok: I am 2.3.2 on android. So, can you point me to some source.

Comment: Asok*. What do you mean "source", are you wanting to building your own logcat application? I provided a link in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the open source [android-log-collector](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/).

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a "LogFacade" class to control log output.  My applications write to LogFacade rather than invoking the Android logger directly.  This permits me to disable log output for production.  LogFacade also has a mode which writes to file on SD card and there is companion diagnostic Activity to read this file.  Perhaps you could try something similar?  Good luck w/your project.